# Showing a progressBar in a popup

Tags: android

I have a popup dialog box in which I am loading a webview. I want to show a progressBar while the webview is loading on top of the popup window.
I have found a way to show loading progressbar while the webpage loads but if this webview is loading in the popup dialog box the progressBar is not shown on top of it.
Can someone explain the reason why this is happening.

Here is the code

[code]

```
 @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void showPopUp(String url){
            try{

                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Links.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Links.this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.link_popup, null);
                dialog.setContentView(vi);
                dialog.setTitle("Title here");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                WebView wb = (WebView) vi.findViewById(R.id.WebView01);

                wb.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
                wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
                wb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);      
                wb.loadUrl(url);
//              final Activity MyActivity = this;  
//              
//              progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(dialog.getOwnerActivity(), "", "Loading....", true);
//              
//              wb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
//               public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
//               {
//                   MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded
//                   if(progress == 100){
//                    if(progressDialog.isShowing())
//                           progressDialog.dismiss();
//                   }
//                 }
//               }); 

                System.out.println("..loading url..");  
                dialog.show();

             }catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println("Exception while showing Agreement : " + e.getMessage());
             }
        }
```

[/code]

It was not working so I commented it.

```
link_popup.xml
```

[code]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="fill"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:background="#000000"
>

        <ProgressBar

            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="5dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
            android:max="100"
            android:background="#228b22"
         />
        <WebView  
            android:id="@+id/WebView01"
            android:layout_below="@id/progressbar_Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scrollbars="@null"
          />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[/code]

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at your code, but if you look at the xml, you have a RelativeLayout, a ProgessBar and a WebView.

When this is inflated, it will first draw the RelativeLayout, than your Progessbar, and finally your WebView. Since your webview has fill_parent on the width and height, the ProgressBar will stay behind the WebView...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:background="#000000">

    <!-- First the WebView -->
    <WebView  
        android:id="@+id/WebView01"
        android:layout_below="@id/progressbar_Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scrollbars="@null"
      />

      <!-- Than the Progessbar on top of it -->
      <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
        android:max="100"
        android:background="#228b22"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No I want to show a progressbar dynamically as I commented in my code.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively , u can make ur activity appear like a dialog using this in manifest file:
in the activity tag

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

and then u can show progress bar , using `async task` in ur activity while the page loads

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This class will show a dialog containing a webview that will show a spinner/progress every time it is loading a webpage/website.

```
/**
 * @author Sherif
 * 
 * Copyright 2011
 *
 * Dialog that will enable web browsing with a progress dialog.
 *
 */

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyLovelyDialog extends Dialog {
    static final float[] DLANDSCAPE = {20, 60};
    static final float[] DPORTRAIt = {40, 60};
    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams mFrameLayoutParams =
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                         ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    private String mUrl;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    public MyLovelyDialog(Context context, String url) {
        super(context);
        mUrl = url;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setUpProgressDialog();
        setUpContent();
        setUpWebView();
        setUpDisplay();
    }
    private void setUpProgressDialog() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        mProgressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    }
    private void setUpContent() {
        mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    }
    private void setUpDisplay() {
        Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final float scale =
            getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int orientation =
            getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        float[] dimensions =
            (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                    ? DLANDSCAPE : DPORTRAIt;
        addContentView(mLinearLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                display.getWidth() - ((int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f)),
                display.getHeight() - ((int) (dimensions[1] * scale + 0.5f))));
    }
    private void setUpWebView() {
        mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyLovelyDialog.MyLovelyWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(mFrameLayoutParams);
        mLinearLayout.addView(mWebView);
    }
    private class MyLovelyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off in a Relative Layout the item positioned closest to the bottom in the XML order will be shown on top. So you must move the XML for your progress bar below the webview so you can see the bar on top of the webview. In your `MyWebViewClient`, you should override [onPageFinished](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) and inside of that function change the [visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) of the progress bar to `GONE`. You may want to pass a reference to the progress bar into the constructor for you `MyWebViewClient` so it can be used to set the visibility to `GONE`.

Example:

```
    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        private ProgressBar pBar;

        public MyWebViewClient(ProgressBar pBar)
        {
            super();
            this.pBar = pBar;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url)
        {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your java code, make these changes:

```
//              progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(dialog.getOwnerActivity(), "", "Loading....", true);
//              
//              wb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
//               public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
//               {
//                   MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded
//                   if(progress == 100){
//                    if(progressDialog.isShowing())
//                           progressDialog.dismiss();
//                   }
//                 }
//               });
```

Change to:

```
              progressDialog = (ProgressDialog) vi.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_horizontal);

              wb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
               public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
               {
                   progressDialog.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded
                   if(progress == 100){
                    if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                           progressDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   }
                 }
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Progress Dialog,
check this pages
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
or this one
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html